# Using lambda expressions on joined basic LINQ query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, lambda

When making a basic LINQ query you can later use lambda expressions to add a where clause like this: `query.Where(c => (init.Contains(c.user)));`.

My problem is that I need to add two where clauses on a query that uses a `join` in the basic LINQ query.

I'm trying to replace my old basic LINQ queries with added lambda expressions so that i prevent duplicated code.

This is my code;

```
var query = from c in db.Clgcom
            join u in db.Dvusr
            on c.Comaut equals u.Gitusr
            // && (initialen.Contains(c.Tstusr) // <-- query.Where(c => (initialen.Contains(c.Tstusr)));
            // This is what im trying to replace// ^^ This works because its in the same table
            // || initialen.Contains(u.Clgusr)) // <-- What do i type when i want to include both these conditions?
            && (c.Modid.StartsWith("C")
            || c.Modid.StartsWith("M"))
            select c;

if(filter != null){
    query = query.Where(c => (initialen.Contains(c.Tstusr) 
                             || initialen.Contains(u.Clgusr)));
                             // This doesn't work
}
```

Is there a way to use a lambda expression that would achieve adding these two conditions in my where clause?

Or should i replace ALL basic LINQ queries with using lambda expressions?

Comment: The only part that should be in the join's on is `c.Comaut equals u.Gitusr`.  The rest should be in a where anyway.  Also you could use navigation properties instead if there is a foreign key relationship between `c.Comaut` and `u.Gitusr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to also defer the `select` by selecting both `c` and `u` to begin with and later just selecting `c`.

```
var temp = from c in db.Clgcom
           join u in db.Dvusr on c.Comaut equals u.Gitusr
           where c.Modid.StartsWith("C") || c.Modid.StartsWith("M")
           select new {c, u};

if(filter != null){
    temp = temp.Where(x => initialen.Contains(x.c.Tstusr) 
                           || initialen.Contains(x.u.Clgusr));

var query = temp.Select(x => x.c);
```

If the relationship between `Clgcom` and `Dvusr` is many to one then you could do the following as `Clgcom` should have a `Dvusr` navigation property based on the foreign key relationship.

```
var query = from c in db.Clgcom
            where (c.Modid.StartsWith("C") || c.Modid.StartsWith("M")) && c.Dvuser != null
            select c;

if(filter != null){
    query = query.Where(c => initialen.Contains(c.Tstusr) 
                             || initialen.Contains(c.Dvusr.Clgusr));
```

Comment: YES, the first option worked in my case! thanks alot!